# How can i connect different Google App Engine Version urls to A different domain name?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, networking, dns, google-cloud-dns

When you upload a new version to app engine, let's call it '0001', you can send requests to this version directly using this url: http://0001.myapp.appspot.com

I find it very useful and I made an habit to release my web apps pointing to the corresponding server version. So when I upload version 0002 to the app engine it points to http://0002.myapp.appspot.com, the same goes to version 0003: http://0003.myapp.appspot.com.

My Challenge is that; when i want to link them to custom domains like;

- Version 0001 to be linked to http://www.money.com.
- Version 0002 to be linked to http://app.money.com.
- And Version 0003 to be linked to http://www.facebook.com.

Instead it links the entire AppId "myapp" to "www.money.com".
How do i point them to different domians?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is called "*services*" on App Engine (formerly known as *modules*). Each service can have own version, but you should use it only for development/testing purposes.

Basically your app config have `<module>` option:

```
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>my-app</application>
  <module>mymodule</module>
  <version>0002</version>
</appengine-web-app>
```

You can have different modules deployed on same time, but mapped to different urls/domains by using `dispatch.xml` file:

```
<dispatch-entries>
  <dispatch>
      <url>app.money.com/</url>
      <module>mymodule</module>
  </dispatch>
</dispatch-entries>
```

See also:

- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/converting
- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/dispatchref